# Using a Range in Calc Macro that is determined by highlighted cells, not an absolute cell reference

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

Simple request: I have calc sheets with multiple tables of data, needing to be sorted by values I have defined (this UserDefIndex is all set)?
I am hoping to find a way to write the Macro that will perform this sort on the cells I have highlighted, as opposed to an absolute cell address

I have wandered through each of these, however, the nomenclature is just too obtuse, and I am having difficulty gaining any grasp of the code

- http://www.debugpoint.com/2015/07/get-the-selection-cell-and-range-address-using-macro-in-libreoffice/
- http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php
- https://opensource.com/article/18/2/variables-data-types-libreoffice-basic

  sub sorts_stats
  rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  rem define variables
  dim document   as object
  dim dispatcher as object

  rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  rem get access to the document
  document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
  dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

  rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
  args1(0).Name = "ToPoint"
  args1(0).Value = "$A$3:$D$18"

  dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, args1())

How do I define an area of highlighted cells, as opposed to "$A$3:$D$18", since the size of the range will vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the range manually, then get the selection range

```
Doc = ThisComponent
Sheet = Doc.Sheets(0)
rng = Doc.CurrentSelection
```

Comment: Marked as Answered, because I assume it works. However, I am still unable to understand how to implement this.

Comment: my code answers your question, but I don't know what you want to do next. You have to select manually the range, then run macro

Comment: Yes, Thank You, Patel. My trouble is intergrating your solution into my macro. It is a matter of understanding the usage - what goes where. However, I have done more research and found the keyboard shortcut "ctrl" + "Q" selects the data block around it, and have set my own Hot Keys to accomplish my tasks.